# API testing using Selenium

Tags: json, api, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to API testing. I need to integrate only one flow of API through Selenium as rest of GUI is already present.
I use API url on client browser, I get the result[json format]
I tried on SoapUI [REST] with the url, it gave the result[json format]

But when I try it on Selenium, I'm getting internal server error 500. 
Please let me know the config changes that I need to take care.

```
string apiurl = "https://example.org/alfresco/s/org/alfresco/faceted/search?"
```

Here is the snippet of code i tried

```
URL url = new URL(apiurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        String authString = "user:Password";
        byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authEncoded = new String("Basic "+bytesEncoded);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authEncoded);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)");
        conn.connect();
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
```

I split the URL as

```
URL url = new URL(url);
        conn.setRequestProperty("resource", "/alfresco/s/org/alfresco/faceted/search?");
        conn.setRequestProperty("query", "%28Keywords%3A%27test%27%29");
        conn.setRequestProperty("format", "json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("resource", url+ "alfresco/s/org/alfresco/faceted/search?query=%28Keywords%3A%27test%27%29&count=10&format=json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

Here I get 200 as response, but the response is on the example.org and not on the query appended.

Kindly let me know what is wrong that have done or need to add any information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a little rude and not regarding current topic but I want to prevent you from doing a wrong job in future.

**Using Selenium Webdriver for API testing you'll suffer a lot of pain**.

Selenium Webdriver is not used for this porpuse.

Instead it there are a lot of good automation tools to test API.
One of them is Postman (chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)

Using this tool you'll get much more features and will be able to test any API with any requirenments.

I doubt you'll be able to do it with selenium Webdriver.

Comment: I totally agree with your comment, but here i need to validate API output with GUI output [selenium code]. This is only one flow of API i will be testing. So to compare the results i started to use selenium only.

Comment: When i run the api url through selenium scripts using httpget/httpurlconnection gives me javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:, but i have added the certificate , still i get this error.